# Create additional table in existing SQLITE (without data loss)

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I would like to add an additional table in my existing DB without loss of the data.
So dropping the tables and create them new is no option.
What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be much easier. I use the SQLiteOpenHelper. So the onCreate() is never been called if the DB already exists. When the version number increases, onUpdate() is called. In onUpdate() I have added my new table with "create table if not exists". From the documentation of SQLITE.ORG: However, if the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause is specified as part of the CREATE TABLE statement and a table or view of the same name already exists, the CREATE TABLE command simply has no effect (and no error message is returned). Now the table is created and its fine.

Answer (score 3):

the way I have done it is create a seperate database, copy everything from the current one over to the temp new one then drop the old database do whatever there and then copy the information back from the temp database.

not sure if there is another way to do it but if there is I would love to hear about it

Comment: It seems to be much easier.
I use the SQLiteOpenHelper.
So the onCreate() is never been called if the DB already exists.
When the version number increases, onUpdate() is called.
In onUpdate() I have added my new table with "create table if not exists".
From the documentation of SQLITE.ORG: However, if the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause is specified as part of the CREATE TABLE statement and a table or view of the same name already exists, the CREATE TABLE command simply has no effect (and no error message is returned).
Now the table is created and its fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a new table in existing database then you should do this inside onUpgrade() method like:-

```
 @Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion == xyz) {
        db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_..........NEW);
    }
}
```

Here **xyz** is the old version of database in which you want to add new table.

And remember to update the DATABASE_VERSION

> When we increase the database version then **onUpgrade()** method calls, and using condition add the table.
>
> And also create a new table inside onCreate() with existing tables, for fresh installs like:-

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_..........OLD);
        db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_..........OLD);
        db.execSQL(QUERY_CREATE_TABLE_..........NEW);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper, override onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db), create a String with the table creation query, and then use db.execSQL(String str);

Answer (score -1):

First you should know about onCreate() and onUpgrade() Method

**onCreate -** When your database created for first time onCreate() method get called.When you are installing app for first time always  onCreate() method called

**onUpgrade()-** When you change version of your database then onUpgrade() method call

So new user should get all the table and old user get all upgraded table and new table.

In following example suppose we are adding new table **Table_5** and Altering **Table_4**

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
 //For new User oncreate method will executed an new user get all the table
    db.execSQL( Create_Table );
    db.execSQL( Create_Table2 );
    db.execSQL( Create_Table3 );
    db.execSQL( Create_Table4 );
    db.execSQL( Create_Table5);  
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

      if(oldVersion<newVersion)
        {
           //For old user onUpgrade method is execute 
             db.execSQL( Alter_Table4);
             db.execSQL( Create_Table5);

         }     
}
```